# How to deploy a workflow as part of a site definition?

Tags: workflow, deployment, visual-studio, site-definition

We have a customer that will be creating many sites based on a site definition.

The sites include a list. We would like to connect a workflow to that list such that the workflow starts whenever a new item is added to the list.

We are using SharePoint Foundation 2010 and developing the workflow with Visual Studio 2010.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Do you want the workflow to be part of the site definition? What will the workflow be authored in SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio?

Comment: The workflow will be created in Visual Studio. It can be part of the site definition, all sites that use this list will have the same site definition-

Comment: Did you ever find the answer (or workaround) to this that you can add below?

Comment: @Alex, we coded it in the feature receiver. In our case we needed to be carefull that the list that we were associating the workflow with had been created before we associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.brianfarnhill.com/2009/02/associating-workflows-programatically/

> I have been
>   working on a site that will be using
>   some custom workflows ... I want
>   to associate these workflows as part
>   of the site  creation process ... to
>   do this I created a feature with a
>   receiver class and used code to add
>   the workflow.